# Count Unique Dates Associated with Location

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I am trying to count the total of Unique Dates based on the location.
Context: I trying to create a formula for counting the number of unique dates based on location. My Spreadsheet looks like this

```
A                 B               C                                 
1 **Participant     Location        Date**        
2 Participant-A   High School X   11/7               
3 Participant-B   High School X   11/7
4 Participant-C   High School X   11/8
5 Participant-E   High School Y   11/7
6 Participant-F   High School Z   11/7
7 Participant-G   High School Z   11/8
```

So for example: high School X had 2 different dates. What would the formula be to count the unique dates based on the location? 
This is also being completed on google sheets.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a simple helper column :

`=1/COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,A7,$B$2:$B$7,B7)`

And to get your results :

`=SUMIF($A$2:$A$7,E2,$C$2:$C$7)`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way (with no helper columns) would be to use query() and unique().

```
=query(unique(B:C), "Select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 <>'' group by Col1 label count(Col2)'# of unique dates'", 1)
```

Illustration:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not one-formula solution but I think it works. First, create a third column concatenating the columns that you want to compare. In this case, at cell `D2` write:

```
=CONCATENATE(B2,C2)
```

This is for the first row of your example. Then, replicate that to the following rows.
Finally, create a formula that counts unique values:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(LEN(D2:D7)>0,MATCH(D2:D7,D2:D7,0),""), IF(LEN(D2:D7)>0,MATCH(D2:D7,D2:D7,0),""))>0,1))
```

Assuming your new column of concatenated values is at `D2:D7`.